# Is there a listener that listens to the enable/disable event in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, listener

Is there a listener I can add to a Swing combobox that will trigger when the combobox is enabled or disabled?

I have tried different listeners like componentlistener, itemlistener, propertychangelistener but in vain. I'm using JDK 1.6.

Comment: [Listeners Supported by Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html), voting to close too

Comment: I agree with you @Duncan. He wants a solution and there is nothing wrong in question. mKorbel must try to answer it instead.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PropertyChangeListener` seems to work just fine for me...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class EnabledTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EnabledTest();
    }

    public EnabledTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
            add(cb, gbc);
            cb.addPropertyChangeListener("enabled", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("State changed for " + evt.getPropertyName() + " to " + evt.getNewValue());
                }
            });

            JButton btn = new JButton("Switch");
            add(btn, gbc);
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cb.setEnabled(!cb.isEnabled());
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This may be a minor issue for most use cases, but I think it's worth noting that this implementation will only work if the enabled/disabled status is set via `JComponent.setEnabled(boolean)`. I did some tests and the property change is not triggered if the enabled state is called by the deprecated methods `JComponent.enable()`, `JComponent.disable()`, or `JComponent.enable(boolean)`. It also doesn't seem to work for `Component.setEnabled(boolean)` (for components that extend Component, but not JComponent).

Comment: @NateW Since we are talking about Swing specifically, then yes, I'm not surprised that you have issues with both `java.awt.Component` and the deprecated functionality